# VTK rendering not working as expected inside PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, qt, rendering, pyqt5, vtk

I need to integrate a VTK visualization inside a PyQt application. However, when I put a model inside a QVTKRenderWindowInteractor the display shows some undesired transparency effect (see picture below). This happens for surfaces or point clouds, whatever I try to load.

Is there any way to achieve the proper representation inside a QVTKRenderWindowInteractor?

First picture is a cone from `vtk.vtkConeSource()`.

[image: Cone; Left: Without QVTKRenderWindowInteractor. Right: With QVTKRenderWindowInteractor]

Second picture is a *[cturtle.pcd](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/test/cturtle.pcd)* pointcloud from PCL Tests.

[image: Cturtle; Left: Without QVTKRenderWindowInteractor. Right: With QVTKRenderWindowInteractor]

***Left:*** Without QVTKRenderWindowInteractor. **Right:** With QVTKRenderWindowInteractor

I attach an example code of the problem for reproduction.
This is the code without Qt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import vtk
from vtk.util.colors import tomato

"""This simple example shows how to do basic rendering and pipeline creation."""

cone = vtk.vtkConeSource()
cone.SetResolution(8)

coneMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
coneMapper.SetInputConnection(cone.GetOutputPort())

coneActor = vtk.vtkActor()
coneActor.SetMapper(coneMapper)
coneActor.GetProperty().SetColor(tomato)
coneActor.RotateX(30.0)
coneActor.RotateY(-45.0)

ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)


ren.AddActor(coneActor)
ren.SetBackground(0.1, 0.2, 0.4)

iren.Initialize()

ren.ResetCamera()
ren.GetActiveCamera().Zoom(1.5)
renWin.Render()

iren.Start()
```

And this is the equivalent display inside a QVTKRenderWindowInteractor:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import vtk
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
from vtk.util.colors import tomato

"""A simple example that uses the QVTKRenderWindowInteractor class."""


app = QApplication(['QVTKRenderWindowInteractor'])

cone = vtk.vtkConeSource()
cone.SetResolution(8)

coneMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
coneMapper.SetInputConnection(cone.GetOutputPort())

coneActor = vtk.vtkActor()
coneActor.SetMapper(coneMapper)
coneActor.GetProperty().SetColor(tomato)
coneActor.RotateX(30.0)
coneActor.RotateY(-45.0)

ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
widget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor()
widget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(ren)

ren.AddActor(coneActor)
ren.SetBackground(0.1,0.2,0.4)

widget.Initialize()

ren.ResetCamera()
ren.GetActiveCamera().Zoom(1.5)
widget.GetRenderWindow().Render()

widget.Start()

widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on Mac OS 10.11.6 and VTK 8.1. What version of VTK are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After trying several things, I got the solution reading the following [Merge Request](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/merge_requests/1097/diffs?commit_id=1da26e338a33778a57078531256faf434fc4b593).

I used QGLWidget as the base class of the QVTKRenderWindowInteractor, instead of QWidget. This change is because it is reported that sometimes QWidget can cause rendering problems.

To do this I put the following code before importing QVTKRenderWindowInteractor:

```
import vtk.qt
vtk.qt.QVTKRWIBase = "QGLWidget"

from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
```

In order to use QGLWidget I had to install the following package:

> sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtopengl

Comment: This solution no longer work. My environment setup: Manjaro==20.1.2; python==3.8.5; VTK==8.2.0; PyQt==5.15.1

Comment: I ran into this on Ubuntu 20.04, qt 5.12.8, and vtk 7.1.1.  In addition to the weird pseudo-transpancy effects, the first thing that I noticed was that one actor would always get rendered in front of another, regardless of the true depth in the scene. 
 This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for newer version of vtk:

```
# this should be done before importing vtk
import vtkmodules.qt
vtkmodules.qt.QVTKRWIBase = 'QGLWidget'

import vtk
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment, I cannot reproduce the problem with VTK 8.1 on MacOS 10.11.6. In case you are running an older version, consider upgrading.

Below is another example where the `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor` widget is embedded in a `QMainWindow`. Does the problem persist?

If yes, compare the output of `print(self.ren)` that I attached below. I'd report this on the [vtk issue tracker](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/issues).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import vtk
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
from vtk.util.colors import tomato

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self,).__init__(parent)

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.vl = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame)
        self.vl.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)
        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.ren.SetBackground(0.5,0.5,0.5)
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

        source = vtk.vtkConeSource()
        source.SetResolution(8)
        mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())
        actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)
        actor.GetProperty().SetColor(tomato)
        actor.RotateX(30.0)
        actor.RotateY(-45.0)

        self.ren.AddActor(actor)
        self.ren.SetBackground(0.1, 0.2, 0.4)
        self.ren.ResetCamera()
        self.ren.GetActiveCamera().Zoom(1.5)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.vl)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

        # Print the renderer.
        print(self.ren)

        self.show()
        self.iren.Initialize()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Console output:

```
vtkOpenGLRenderer (0x7ff4c3d8a5f0)
  Debug: Off
  Modified Time: 1159
  Reference Count: 2
  Registered Events: (none)
  Aspect: (1, 1)
  PixelAspect: (1, 1)
  Background: (0.1, 0.2, 0.4)
  Background2: (0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
  BackgroundAlpha: 0
  GradientBackground: Off
  Viewport: (0, 0, 1, 1)
  Displaypoint: (0, 0, 0)
  Viewpoint: (0, 0, 0)
  Worldpoint: (0, 0, 0, 0)
  Pick Position X1 Y1: -1 -1
  Pick Position X2 Y2: -1 -1
  IsPicking boolean: 0
  Props:
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 923
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Number Of Items: 1
  PickResultProps:
  nullptr
  Near Clipping Plane Tolerance: 0.001
  ClippingRangeExpansion: 0.5
  Ambient: (1, 1, 1)
  Backing Store: Off
  Display Point: (0, 0, 0)
  Lights:
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 806
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Number Of Items: 0
  Light Follow Camera: On
  View Point: (0, 0, 0)
  Two Sided Lighting: On
  Automatic Light Creation: On
  Layer = 0
  PreserveDepthBuffer: Off
  PreserveColorBuffer: Off
  Interactive = On
  Allocated Render Time: 10000
  Last Time To Render (Seconds): -1
  TimeFactor: 1
  Erase: On
  Draw: On
  UseDepthPeeling: Off
  OcclusionRation: 0
  MaximumNumberOfPeels: 4
  LastRenderingUsedDepthPeeling: Off
  Delegate:null
  Selector: 0x0
  TexturedBackground: Off
  BackgroundTexture:null
  Pass:null
  PickedId0
  NumPicked0
  PickedZ 0
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and the version of VTK is 8.1.1. I  tried your code and the problem persist. The output of `self.ren` seems the same as yours.

Comment: Alright. I am inclined to classify your problem as a bug. As a last thing, you could play with the face-culling options of the actor. See [`vtkProperty`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkProperty.html). Does this change anything?

Comment: If I add `coneActor.GetProperty().SetBackfaceCulling(1)` the cone is displayed correctly (probably because it is a surface). But for example in a point cloud, the points of the background still are displayed above those in front.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on multiple machines? Since OpenGL is involved, it is possible that the problem is related to a driver problem.